# Trying to find the time for different paths for a traversing ball between two points under the influence of gravity, but I need some help?

Tags: calculus, physics, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to find the time for different paths for a traversing ball between two points under the influence of gravity, but I am getting strange results for a reason I don't understand, I feel like I am missing something.

Time is equal to:
$$
T=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2g}}\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1+(y')^2}{y}}dx
$$
where $y$ is the functions I am trying to test.

My two points are $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, the former one being the starting point. I am trying to use a circle as one of my tests:
$$
(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2
$$
Expressing $y$ as a function of $x$:
$$
y=k\pm \sqrt{r^2-(x-h)^2}
$$
And finally:
$$
y=1-\sqrt{1^2-(x-1)^2}.
$$
So I input the above and its derivative into my time equation:
$$
T=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2g}}\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{1+\bigg(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt{1-(x-1)^{2}}}\bigg)^2}{1-\sqrt{1^2-(x-1)^2}}}dx
$$
But when putting this into Desmos it gives me $6.060$, which seems way longer than expected given that a straight line only takes $0.63$ seconds.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Use another solution: $y=1+\sqrt{1^2-(x-1)^2}$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, however that would give me the top half of the circle, I am only interested in the bottom half which connects the two points I have mentioned.

Comment: Your time formula looks like it is lacking an energy constant $$
T=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}}\int_0^{x_{max}}\frac{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}{\sqrt{C_0+y}}dx
$$

Comment: The problem with your integration is that near $x=1$ the process slows down. Try the range $[0,0.9]$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer to a related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4791711/i-am-trying-to-find-the-time-for-different-paths-for-a-traversing-ball-between-t/4791728#comment10197572_4791728) by the same user also answers it.